# Calling rosbag info from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ros

When you call ROS `rosbag info abag.bag` you get something like

```
path:        abag.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    1:35s (95s)
start:       Aug 23 2021 03:34:46.34 (1629689686.34)
end:         Aug 23 2021 03:36:21.45 (1629689781.45)
size:        1.1 GB
messages:    952
compression: none [952/952 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/Image [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
topics:      image_results   952 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
```

Is there a way to call this program from a bash shell file and then extract *only* one field (for example *messages*) to compare it to something

In pseudo code something like

```
call rosbag info and get messages
if messages== 952
then print("everything ok")
else print("some messages were skipped"
```

Is this possible in bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you actually can. `rosbag info` has a flag, `-k`, for pulling out specific fields; you'll also need to use `-y` for this to work. So, in your example pulling out the number of messages would look like `rosbag info -y -k messages abag.bag`. If you wanted to put all of this in a bash script it could look something like where you would pass the expected number of messages in as a command line parameter:

```
expectedNum=$1
actualNum=$(rosbag info -y -k messages abag.bag)
if (( expectedNum==actualNum )); then
    echo "everything okay"
else
    echo "everything not okay"
fi
```